# Python: How to make a function that asks for the exact amount of words?

Tags: python, python-2.7, word-count

Here's what I have so far:

```
import string
```

So I have the user write a 5 worded sentence asking for only 5 words:

```
def main(sentence = raw_input("Enter a 5 worded sentence: ")):
    if len(words)<5:
        words = string.split(sentence)
        wordCount = len(words)
        print "The total word count is:", wordCount
```

If the user inputs more than 5 words:

```
    elif len(words)>5:
        print 'Try again. Word exceeded 5 word limit'
```

Less than 5 words:

```
    else:
        print 'Try again. Too little words!'
```

It keeps stating that:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'words' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: When asking a question, please say what the problem is.

Comment: `string.split(sentence)`? You should upgrade to Python2 or better so you can say `sentence.split()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calling `len(words)` before the variable `words` exists.  This is in the second line of your second code block.

```
words = []
while len(words) != 5:
  words = raw_input("Enter a 5 worded sentence: ").split()
  if len(words) > 5:
    print 'Try again. Word exceeded 5 word limit'
  elif len(words) < 5:
    print 'Try again. Too little words!'
```

---

Note that in python, default arguments are bound at time of function *definition* rather than at function call time.  This means your `raw_input()` will fire when main is defined rather then when main is called, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: What more is there to explain...?

Comment: Hahaha I know what you mean, but you know what I meant :P now it's better

Comment: One thing that might be good to explain is why calling raw_input() in the def is such a bad idea..

Comment: yeah, added a note about that

Answer (score 1):

Read your own output :): the 'words' variable is referenced before assignment.

In other words, you are calling len(words) before saying what 'words' means!

```
def main(sentence = raw_input("Enter a 5 worded sentence: ")):
    if len(words)<5: # HERE! what is 'words'?
        words = string.split(sentence) # ah, here it is, but too late!
        #...
```

Try defining it before attempting to use it:

```
words = string.split(sentence)
wordCount = len(words)
if wordCount < 5:
    #...
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the inputs using raw_input().
Do the wordcount using Split()
and then re-read if it is not equal to 5.

Answer (score 0):

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'words' referenced before assignment

This means exactly what it says. You are trying to use `words` before the part where you figure out what the `words` actually are.

Programs proceed step-by-step. Be methodical.