# Python: How to use a while loop and output the correct word count

Tags: python, while-loop, python-2.7, word-count

This is what I have so far:

```
while len(words) != 5:
        words = raw_input("Enter a 5 worded sentence: ").split()
        print "Try again. The word count is:", wordCount
if len(words) == 5:
        print "Good! The word count is 5!"
```

The problem is I get this:

```
Enter a 5 worded sentence: d d d d
Try again. The word count is: 4
Enter a 5 worded sentence: d d d d d d 
Try again. The word count is: 4
Enter a 5 worded sentence: d d d d d 
Try again. The word count is: 4
Good! The word count is 5!
```

When I enter more or less than 5 words, it keeps that word count and doesn't change.

Comment: Where are you initializing variable `wordCount`?

Comment: I placed it before the while loop. wordCount=len(words)

Comment: Make sure you post the actual code that generated your output.  As is, your code will fail since `words` is not defined before testing the length.

Comment: double-post of  http://stackoverflow.com/q/9407005/674039

Answer (score 3):

Since Python doesn't have a `do-while` loop like some other languages, this idiom prevents duplication of the `raw_input` function, and makes sure the loop runs at least once.  Make sure to update `word_count` after getting new input.

```
while 1:
    words = raw_input("Enter a 5 worded sentence: ").split()
    word_count = len(words)
    if word_count == 5: break
    print "Try again. The word count is:", word_count
print "Good! The word count is 5!"
```

Comment: Could we please not teach beginners to write ugly things like `while 1`?

Comment: That doesn't make it right. It's a gross violation of the Zen IMHO.

Comment: In Python 2, `while 1` generates a more efficient loop.  In Python 3, it no longer makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to re-order some of your logic:

```
# prompt before entering loop
words = raw_input("Enter a 5 worded sentence: ").split()
while len(words) != 5:
        print "Try again. The word count is:", len(words)
        words = raw_input("Enter a 5 worded sentence: ").split()

# no need to test len again
print "Good! The word count is 5!"
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable wordCount should be updated inside the loop, after you accept the input. Only then it will reflect the new value. Something like this:-

```
while len(words) != 5:
    words = raw_input("Enter a 5 worded sentence: ").split()
    wordCount = len(words)
    print "Try again. The word count is:", wordCount
if len(words) == 5:
    print "Good! The word count is 5!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code snippet is missing parts. Anyways, you should evaluate the `wordCount` after `raw_input` so that it gets updated with new values.

```
wordCount = 0
while wordCount != 5:
    words = raw_input("Enter a 5 worded sentence: ").split()
    wordCount = len(words)
    print "Try again. The word count is:", wordCount

print "Good! The word count is 5!"
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about that wordCount = 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
def xlen(string_data):
    try:
        count = 0
        while 1:
            string_data[count]
            count = count + 1
    except(IndexError):
        print count

xlen('hello')
```